# Can't install any programs on Ubuntu 16.04 after trying to use command to install runescape

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, software-sources

```
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I've been through everything, resetting repositories/sources, and when I did that it seemed to mess up further, now I have the little circle with a white line running through it in the top right of my screen. Have spent over a day trying to resolve this and I can't install anything at all. I even made a new account hoping it would reset my settings, which seemed to work for a minute (red circle went away) but then it seemed to go right back to how it was. Sorry if I missed any crucial information, this is my third day using Ubuntu.

The link you sent me definitely helped something but in the end the same message. Here's what's happening:

[it's looking like I have the same issue with spotify going on, which was previously workng.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAeiR.png)

Comment: In terminal, show us the output of `sudo cat  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list`, and we can fix that first. Just edit your question to include the output that you copy/pasted. And tell us, what command did you use to try and install runescape?

Comment: "N: Ignoring file 'runescape.list.bk' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension" if I try installing vlc or anything else

Comment: You should find some help here: [How do I restore the default repositories?](//askubuntu.com/q/124017)/

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you didn't follow the instructions on how to install runescape. You ended up coping the install instructions file to /etc/apt/sources.list.d, instead of executing the file or the commands contained therein.

So, do the following (best to use copy and paste for the **blue** commands):

1. start **terminal** from the Unity dashboard and enter the commands in **blue**, shown below.
2. `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list ~/Desktop/runescape_install.sh`
3. `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list.bk`

   If you get errors in step #2, stop here. Report back.
4. `cd ~/Desktop`
5. `sudo chown camshas:camshas runescape_install.sh`
6. `sudo apt-get update`

   If there are any further errors in step 6, report back with exact details.
7. `cd ~/Desktop`
8. `cat runescape_install.sh`
9. select all of the text output, right-click on the selected text, and choose **copy**
10. right-click on any blank area in the terminal window, and select **paste**, and hit the **enter** key. Enter your password when prompted.

**update**: the user was changing things on his own while I was trying to assist. Ignore steps 1-10, I deleted the runescape files in /etc/apt/source.list.d, and instructed the user to start install from the beginning, following the instructions found at https://www.runescape.com/download.

Comment: How do I open terminal with blue commands? I did what you said with green commands and this is what showed: camshas@george:~$ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list ~/Desktop/runescape_install.sh
[sudo] password for camshas: 
mv: cannot stat '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list': No such file or directory
camshas@george:~$

Comment: "terminal" wasn't a BLUE command. You start it from the Unity dashboard just like any application. If the BLUE command from step #2 failed, it's because you've changed things since you posted your question. In terminal, type `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*` and report back.

Comment: I entered that(ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*)and this is what I received: 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list.bk
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list.save

Comment: I'm just gonna stop working on it myself and only do what I'm told so as to not mess up any diagnosis

Comment: In terminal, type `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list` and report back.

Comment: cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list: No such file or directory

Comment: did you type **cat:**, or **cat**?

Comment: I typed **cat**

Comment: Arrgh. In terminal, type `sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*` and it'll ask you to approve the removal of 3 files with runescap somewhere in the filename.

Comment: and then what, I just hit **y**?

Comment: 'camshas@george:~$ sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*
[sudo] password for camshas: 
rm: remove regular file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list.save'? y

I tried it twice since after typing **y** nothing seemed to happen, and the second time the response was:
camshas@george:~$ sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescap*': No such file or directory'

Comment: As I said earlier, you MUST have been changing things on your own, while I was trying to help you at the same time. **Very frustrating.** Go to https://www.runescape.com/download, **copy** (to the clipboard) the install instructions shown in green, and **paste** (by right-clicking) into an open terminal window.

Comment: I did that, picture is in original post for you to see everything in my terminal. I dont care about runescape working I just need it to stop interfering with all my other downloads

Comment: I didn't just ask you to **cat** again, I asked you to **copy and paste the instructions** found at the web site. I can't spend any more time on this. Sorry.